# How to merge a frame to photo and save it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm trying to build an application where you can select multiple images and then show how it would look like (preview). this is the modal I'm trying to build: [poloaroid frame photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p9FB.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea how it's done?

I tried merging the image using image package with a white image from assets but I ran into many issues and haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your frame under your image using `Stack()`, and then place the whole widget using Libary [WidgetsToImage](https://pub.dev/packages/widgets_to_image). Then you could download the image file using the library [Image Downloader Web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader_web).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).